# Infopath 2010 Add in development

Tags: 2010, infopath, visual-studio

I have a requirement to create a custom add in infopath form which will only be implemented in a single form library i.e. if users opens infopath forms in different form library then they will not be able to see the addins.

I am not getting any articles on development of addins for infopath 2010 also.

Please someone help me out.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Plz somebody help me out in this...I am going no where..

Comment: Just to let you know folks are listening... (even late!)